# Why is my download from Azure storage empty?

Tags: c#, download, azure-storage, azure-files

I can connect to the Azure Storage account and can even upload a file, but when I go to download the file using DownloadToFileAsync() I get a 0kb file as a result.

I have checked and the "CloudFileDirectory" and the "CloudFile" fields are all correct, which means the connection with Azure is solid. I can even write the output from the file to the console, but I cannot seem to save it as a file.

```
public static string PullFromAzureStorage(string azureFileConn, string remoteFileName, string clientID)
        {
            var localDirectory = @"C:\cod\clients\" + clientID + @"\ftp\";
            var localFileName = clientID + "_xxx_" + remoteFileName;

            //Retrieve storage account from connection string
            var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(azureFileConn);
            var client = storageAccount.CreateCloudFileClient();
            var share = client.GetShareReference("testing");

            // Get a reference to the root directory for the share
            CloudFileDirectory rootDir = share.GetRootDirectoryReference();
            //Get a ref to client folder
            CloudFileDirectory cloudFileDirectory = rootDir.GetDirectoryReference(clientID);
            // Get a reference to the directory we created previously
            CloudFileDirectory unprocessed = cloudFileDirectory.GetDirectoryReference("Unprocessed");
            // Get a reference to the file
            CloudFile sourceFile = unprocessed.GetFileReference(remoteFileName);

            //write to console and log
            Console.WriteLine("Downloading file: " + remoteFileName);
            LogWriter.LogWrite("Downloading file: " + remoteFileName);

            //Console.WriteLine(sourceFile.DownloadTextAsync().Result);
            sourceFile.DownloadToFileAsync(Path.Combine(localDirectory, localFileName), FileMode.Create);

            //write to console and log
            Console.WriteLine("Download Successful!");
            LogWriter.LogWrite("Download Successful!");

            //delete remote file after download
            //sftp.DeleteFile(remoteDirectory + remoteFileName);

            return localFileName;    
        }
```

Comment: ```sourceFile.DownloadToFileAsync(Path.Combine(localDirectory, localFileName), FileMode.Create).GetAwaiter().GetResult();```

Comment: Thanks! This solution works for sure. Working on being able to make the method async so I can use the original statement possibly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the commented out line of code where you write the output to the Console, you explicitly use `.Result` because you're calling an `async` method in a synchronous one. You should either also do so while downloading the file as well, or make the entire method around it `async`.

The first solution would look something like this:

`sourceFile.DownloadToFileAsync(Path.Combine(localDirectory, localFileName), FileMode.Create).Result();`

**EDIT:**
As far as the difference with the comment, that uses `GetAwaiter().GetResult()`, goes: `.Result` wraps any exception that might occur in an `AggregateException`, while `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` won't. Anyhow: if there's any possibility you can refactor the method to be `async` so you can use `await`: please do so.

Comment: When I await that statement and make the method async (my preferred method also), I get this as a response.
```System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1+AsyncStateMachineBox`1[System.String,ComplianceOnDemand.FileHandler+<PullFromAzureStorageAsync>d__3]```

Comment: Also, when I try to use .Result on that statement I get 
```'Task' does not contain a definition for 'Result' and no accessible extension method 'Result' accepting a first argument of type 'Task' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```